# Timeout exceeded Mocha + Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem in this test. I don't know why the insertion works, but if I run the test I receive:

> Error: Timeout of 15000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

**CODE**

```
describe('CRUD on Product', function () {
  this.timeout(15000)
  it('Insert single Product', function (done) {
    Product.build({
      Customer: customer,
      Order: order
    }, {
      include: [Customer, Order]
    }).save(function (mind) {
      console.log(mind)
      done();
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      done()
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown is this [tutorial](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html), the `save` function does not take callback as parameter. It returns a `promise`.

```
describe('CRUD on Product', function () {
  this.timeout(15000)
  it('Insert single Product', function (done) {
    Product.build({
      Customer: customer,
      Order: order
    }, {
      include: [Customer, Order]
    })
    .save()
    .then(function (mind) {
      console.log(mind)
      done();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      done()
    })
  });
});
```